# Paying credits after a failled spacemission

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you start a spacemission you have to pay some credits to go to the destination.

If I die during a spacemission and I press the button "retry mission". Do I have to pay that money again, or can I try the mission again without paying the credits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Retry mission" is free, but if you back out and try the same mission again you'll need to pay again (since the game keeps you at the last planet you were at).